# jQuery .toggleClass() não está a funcionar como esperado

Tags: jquery, opacity

Tenho este código mas não entendo porquê o método `.toggleClass()` não está a funcionar como esperado para alterar a opacidade do elemento:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dW6Mb/16/)

**HTML**

```html
<div id="admin">
    <p><br/>Admin</p>
    <form method="POST" action="loginAdmin.php">Username:
        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <br />Password:
        <br/>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
        <br />
        <div id="button">
            <button id="btn" name="send" type="submit" value="enviar">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#admin {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 140px;
    right: 200px;
    width: 224px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 140px;
}
#admin p {
    font-family: Lato-Light;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 11px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.adminPvisible {
    opacity:1;
}
#admin p:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
#admin form {
    display: none;
    font-family:Lato-Light;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin:35px 0 0 100px;
}
#btn {
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    font-family: Lato-Regular;
}
#admin input {
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#admin > p').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('adminPvisible');
        var right = $('#admin > p').css('right') == '135px' ? '0' : '135px';
        $('#admin > p').animate({
            right: right,
            width: '50px'
        });
        $('#admin > form, #btn').stop(true).slideToggle();        
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já referenciado em outras respostas, o jQuery [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> está a funcionar, o problema é a classe de CSS tem uma prioridade mais baixa que as definições dadas previamente via `#admin p`.

De forma resumida, ao passares estilos para o selector `#admin p` estás a ser muito rigoroso, e quando uma classe *não rigorosa* é atribuída, o navegador não a vai respeitar para sobrepor as definições.

Duas formas simples de resolveres a tua questão:

1. ### Classes para cada definição

   Ao invés de usares uma classe para sobrescreve a definição de um elemento, se essa definição é mutável, o mais prático é teres duas classes, cada uma com o estado pretendido e alternar entre elas:

   [**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/2eYLZ/)

   **CSS**

   ```css
   .adminPnearInvisible {
       opacity: 0.3;
   }
   .adminPvisible {
       opacity:1;
   }
   ```

   **HTML**

   ```html
   <div id="admin">
       <p class="adminPnearInvisible"><br/>Admin</p>
       ...
   ```

   **jQuery**

   ```js
   ...
   $(this).toggleClass('adminPvisible adminPnearInvisible');
   ...
   ```

   O que estamos a fazer é usar o [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> para alternar duas classes. Como estava no elemento a classe `.adminPnearInvisible`, ao alternar entre ela e a `.adminPvisible`, estamos efectivamente a remover uma e adicionar outra, atribuindo assim ao elemento o estilo que cada uma contém sem precisarmos de nos preocupar com os estilos "base" do elemento.
2. ### Definir de forma rigorosa o estilo a subscrever

   Podes optar por definir com o mesmo rigor os dois estados da opacidade, o que vai dizer ao navegador que prevalece o que vem em 2º lugar se aplicável:

   [**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/b3V4w/)

   **CSS**

   Passamos a ter a tua classe `.adminPvisible` com o mesmo rigor dos estilos do elemento onde defines a opacidade inicial. Como já tens o valor no `:hover`, estou a juntar as duas coisas para evitar duplicar declarações na folha de estilos:

   ```css
   #admin p:hover,
   #admin p.adminPvisible{
       opacity: 1;
   }
   ```

   **HTML**

   Sem alterações ao teu inicial...

   **jQuery**

   Sem alterações ao teu inicial...

---

Não relacionado mas pode ser útil é uma ligeira optimização do teu código para reduzir o mesmo e ao mesmo tempo evitar consultas recorrentes ao DOM para localizar o mesmo elemento:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/QXhLZ/)

```
$('#admin > p').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('adminPvisible').animate({
        right: $this.css('right') == '135px' ? '0' : '135px'
    });
    $('#admin > form, #btn').stop(true).slideToggle();        
});
```

Explicação

```
// colocar elemento em cache para não andarmos sempre à procura dele
var $this = $(this);

// jQuery permite encadeamento dos métodos, por isso numa linha podes
// fazer a alternância da classe e chamar a animação
$this.toggleClass('adminPvisible').animate(...

// podes ter a verificação do valor e atribuição do novo para a animação
// na declaração do valor pretendido para animar o right
right: $this.css('right') == '135px' ? '0' : '135px'
```

E passei a largura de `50px` para a folha de estilos pois a mesma não está a ser manipulada, ou seja, estás a dizer que a partir do primeiro clique o elemento fica com 50 pixeis de largura.

Comment: Muito obgado mais uma vez Zuul, muito claro e directo à questão, esclareceste mais do que uma duvida. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

O que está acontecendo não é uma falha do jQuery, porém uma função do CSS.

Ele é organizado por ordem de especificidade, regras com maior prioridade são aplicadas mesmo se declaradas antes das de menor especificidade. Aplica-se uma regra de pontuação:

- Estilos vindos do atributo `style` valem 1000 pontos, ids (`#admin`), 100 pontos, classes (`.adminPvisible`), 10 pontos, e tags(`p`) tem prioridade mínima, 1 ponto.
- Pseudo-classes, pseudo-elementos, `@media` e similares não influenciam na pontuação.
- No fim as pontuações são somadas, ou, se forem regras marcadas com `!important` ,tornam-se de prioridade máxima. Caso múltiplas regras encaixem-se na mesma situação ganha a definida pelo `style` ou a última.

Para resolver o problema você tem algumas opções:

- (recomendada) Nunca use IDs no CSS: por eles terem uma especifidade tão alta eles geralmente não podem ser sobrescritos.
- Ao declarar uma regra que vai sobrescrever uma regra definida por uma ID inclua ela junto: `.adminPvisible` vira `#admin > p.adminPvisible`.
- (não recomendado) use `!important`.

Mais informações: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) | [SmashingMagazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) - Demonstração: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dW6Mb/19/)

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente o que faltava era apenas colocar `!important` no [css](/questions/tagged/css) do `.adminPvisible` dessa forma ele força a opacidade ser 1 enquanto a classe estiver no elemento.

No [exemplo que você postou](http://jsfiddle.net/dW6Mb/16/) o `.toggleClass()` funciona perfeitamente, você só precisa dizer que a classe `.adminPvisible` é mais importante que o `#admin p`

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dW6Mb/17/)

Comment: No caso ele adicionar o !important é desnecessário e geralmente deve ser evitado. Ele precisa apenas especificar melhor as regras a serem aplicadas, como dito na resposta do Gustavo Rodrigues